# Uncaught Exception java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: "unable to create new native thread" error occurring while running jmeter in non gui mode

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

My scenario,

**Step1**: I have set my thread group for **1000:threads & 500:seconds**
**Step2**:Configure heep space : **HEAP=-Xms1024m -Xmx1024m**
**Step3**:Now, running jmeter for non gui mode. 
In this scenario,"Uncaught Exception **java.lang.OutOfMemoryError**: unable to create new native thread" error occuring in my system.

**My system configuration**

**Processor**:Intel® Pentium(R) CPU G2010 @ 2.80GHz × 2
**OS Type**:32 bit
**Disc**:252.6GB
**Memory**:3.4 GiB

kindly give me a solution for this scenario.

Thanks,
Vairamuthu.

Comment: 1k threads is going to consume a lot of memory (4M or 8M per thread stack I believe depending on OS), you don't have enough RAM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is due to using a 32 bit OS, in this mode you are limited both in what you can allocate as Heap (depending on OS you will not be able to exceed 1.6 to 2.1 g) and native threads creation.

I'd suggest switching to 64 Bits OS + 64 bits Jdk.

But if you don't have any other option try setting in jmeter.sh in JVM_ARGS:

> -Xss128k

Or if too low:

> -Xss256k

Comment: Hi, I just want to ask how do I set this? do I set it like this? JVM_ARGS="-Xms1024m -Xmx1024m -Xss256k". But this doesn't work.

Answer (score 5):

You **don't have enough memory** in your machine to consume `1000` threads. It is clearly visible from the error that your machine can not create 1000 threads. You should tweak your machine to resolve this situation.

You have to consider these points:

- **JMeter** is a Java tool it runs with **JVM**. To obtain **maximum capability**, we need to provide maximum resources to JMeter during execution.First, we need to increase **heap size** (Inside JMeter bin directory, we get jmeter.bat/sh)

  `HEAP=-Xms512m –Xmx512m`

It means default allocated heap size is **minimum 512MB, maximum 512MB**. Configure it as per you own PC configuration. Keep in mind, OS also need some amount of memory, so **don't allocate all of you physical RAM**.

- Then, add **memory allocation rate**

  `NEW=-XX:NewSize=128m -XX:MaxNewSize=512m`

This means memory will be **increased at this rate**. You should be careful, because, if your **load generation is very high at the beginning**, this might need to increase. Keep in mind, it will fragment your heap space inside JVM if the range too broad. If so **Garbage Collector** needs to work harder to clean up.

- JMeter is Java **GUI application**. It also has the non-GUI edition which is very resource intensive(CPU/RAM). If we run Jmeter in **non-GUI mode** , it will consume less resource and we can run more thread.
- **Disable all the Listeners** during the Test Run. They are only for debugging and use them to design your desired script.

**Listeners** should be disabled **during load tests**. Enabling them causes **additional overheads**, which consume valuable resources (more memory) that are needed by more important elements of your test.

- Always try to use the **Up-to-date software**. Keep your Java and JMeter updated.
- Don’t forget that when it comes to storing requests and response headers, assertion results and response data can consume a **lot of memory**! So try not to store these values on JMeter **unless it’s absolutely necessary**.

Also, you need to **monitor** whether your machine's **`Memory consumption`**, **`CPU usages`** are running **below 80 %** or not. If these usages exceed 80 % consider those tests as unreliable as report.

After all of these, if you can't generate 1000 threads from your machine, then you must try with the [Distributed Load Testing](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/remote-test.html).

Here is a document for [JMeter Distributed Testing Step-by-step](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_distributed_testing_step_by_step.pdf).

For better and more elaborated understanding these two blogs [How many users JMeter can support?](http://shantonusarker.blogspot.com/2015/04/how-many-user-jmeter-can-support.html) and [9 Easy Solutions for a JMeter Load Test “Out of Memory” Failure](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/nine-easy-solutions-jmeter-load-test-%E2%80%9Cout-memory%E2%80%9D-failure) must help.

I have also found this [article](http://theworkaholic.blogspot.com/2009/09/running-jmeter-for-large-number-of.html) very helpful to understand and how to handle them.

Answer (score 2):

The error is due to lack of free RAM.

Looking into your hardware, it doesn't seem you will be able to produce the load of 1k users so I would recommend reconsidering your approach.

For example, you anticipate 1000 simultaneous users working with your application. However it doesn't necessarily mean 100 **concurrent** users as:

- real users don't hammer application non-stop, they need some time to "think" between operations, this "think time" differs depending on application nature, but you should keep it as close to reality as possible
- application response time should be added to think time

So given you have 1000 users, each of them "thinks" 10 seconds between operations and application response time is 2 seconds, each user will be able to send 5 requests per minute (60 / (10 + 2)).

Assuming above scenario 1000 users will send 5000 requests per minute which gives us **~83 requests per second** and it seems to be achievable with your current hardware.

So if you are not in position to get more powerful hardware or more similar machines to use [JMeter in distributed more](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_distributed_testing_step_by_step.pdf), the options are in:

- Add "think times" between operations using i.e. [Constant Timer](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Constant_Timer) or [Uniform Random Timer](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Uniform_Random_Timer)
- Change your test scenario logic to simulate "requests per second" rather than "concurrent users". You can do it using [Constant Throughput Timer](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeters-throughput-constant-timer) or [Throughput Shaping Timer](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ThroughputShapingTimer/).